# Older Computer Not Stable With Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, crash

I have an older desktop computer (about 10 years), a Sony Viao PCV-1132 (I can't find a spec sheet on it), that would not reliably boot up with Windows XP.  The only difference from stock is a wireless card.  The first time it tried to boot it would crash, but the second time was usually stable.  Since XP is essentially no more, I thought I would put Mint 17 32 Bit on it, but some problems still persist.  So, I'm convinced it is hardware, which is not my strong suit.

It will still not boot reliably the first time, but will when it feels like it.  Most of the time, it will either stop functioning with the Mint logo splash screen, or drop to terminal and the last message given is "panic occurred".  I took pictures of the screens, tried the Linux Memtest, and that returned one bad result.  I have no idea if it is serious or not.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas on what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: :( It's serious.  You have some bad RAM (probably also why XP was unreliable).  [`memtest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest) actually isn't a linux utility (it's a bare metal app), but it is included on many install disks.  The only thing you can do is replace it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like from the memory test that your RAM is damaged. If this is the case (which it looks like), new module(s?) should fix the problem.